# US Citizen with UK resident visa - want to travel to Cuba

Tags: cuba

I am a US citizen but I live in the UK.
I have called the Cuban consulate in London and was informed that I am allowed to travel to Cuba, as long as I get the permit.

I worry that due to the Embargo it will bring penalties later on when I enter the US.

Does anybody have any advice on this?

Comment: What is the purpose of your travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you would need to secure a visa through the Cuban consulate, you might also wish to check with the US Consulate. US citizens may not go as tourists but may visit, without penalty, for the following reasons: family visits;  official government business; journalism; professional research and meetings; educational activities; religious activities; public performances, clinics, workshops, exhibitions and athletic competitions; “support for the Cuban people;” humanitarian projects; activities of private foundations or research for educational institutes; exporting or importing information or “information materials;” travel related to some authorized export transactions.

Here's the link to the most recent Treasury FAQs www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Documents/cuba_faqs_new.pdf